# Is there any good JAVA lib for playing with POST-GET requests?

Tags: java, post, get

Search for good JAVA lib for playing with POST-GET requests  - Is there any such lib or how to play with POST - GETS from pure JAVA? How to create costume headers and so on.

Comment: By playing with, do you mean on the client or server side?  I'm assuming client, as server already has the HttpServletResponse class and its addHeader method for sending a custom header in a reply.

Comment: just vote down - 3 questions in 5 minutes, not even an attempt at google or 'the source' (sun) for these questions.

Comment: client  side sending data to server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/index.html). It has pretty much anything you'll need. I use it in production work to connect to REST services from our server. It can handle custom headers, cookies, authentication, etc.

Answer (score 1):

all you need is [java.net.URL](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) to do basic stuff.

Comment: And what I need for going into more adv stuff?

Comment: @OleJak: what kind of more advanced stuff?